# Does CloudFront use a single cache for http and https paths?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cors, amazon-cloudfront

To work around [a Firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=671608) (can't use multiple origin domains in CORS headers), the origin server returns different Access-Control-Allow-Origin values based on the request domain:

- http://example.com/font.woff - `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com`
- https://example.com/font.woff - `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://example.com`
- http://example.org/font.woff - `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.org`

However CloudFront seems to return the http:// value only when requesting https. Origin Protocol Policy is set to match viewer, not HTTP only. Does CloudFront use the same entry per-path on the same domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you configure Cloudfront to forward the protocol, then yes, it will serve the same content.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/header-caching.html#header-caching-web-protocol